# Wildcard character does not behave as a wildcard in google spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, expression, wildcard

I tried the simpliest thing:

[image]

But if I did this:

[image]

the expression was TRUE. So it seems the * character does not behave as a wildcard. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards with the `=` operator.

Try this instead:

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^maki.*")
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a list which functions work with the wildcards?

Comment: Not that I know of. But generally VLOOKUP(), MATCH() and the `... IF(S)` functions accept wildcards e.g. SUMIF(),COUNTIF(),MAXIFS(),MINIFS()...